# Google maps change cursor click point

Tags: google-maps

Maybe this is duplicated question, but I couldnt find answer

I am using Google maps with custom cursor

```
map.setOptions({ draggableCursor : "url(../../img/icons/pin-g-maps.png), auto" })
```

icon that I am using is [image]

Regular ("normal" cursors are hand or windows pointer) and all "normal" cursors have click point in upper left corner, but my custom icon must have click point bottom in the middle that I can get correct lat and long data.

Is this possible and how can I achieve that?
Thx

Comment: is not clear the coord you need , he coord of the marker   or the coord of the map you clicked ?

Comment: coord of marker when I click. By default is upper left corner and if I use custom pin it is in the botoom - middle. like in windows, regular cursor have click point up-left and I want that point down-middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @scaisEdge,
I was looking for this options

```
map.setOptions({draggableCursor: 'url((../../img/icons/pin-g-maps.png) 16 32, auto'});
```